# How to include a template with relative path in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, include, render, jinja2

I'm trying, in a template, to include another one that is in the same folder. To do so, i'm just doing `{% import 'header.jinja2' %}`. The problem is that i keep getting a `TemplateNotFound` error.

My template folder looks like

```
+ myProject
|
+--+ templates
   |
   +--+ arby
   |  |-- header.jinja2
   |  |-- footer.jinja2
   |  +-- base.jinja2
   |
   +--+ bico
      |-- header.jinja2
      |-- footer.jinja2
      +-- base.jinja2
```

So when I render arby's 'base.jinja2' I would like to include 'arby/header.jinja2' and when I render bico's 'base.jinja2' I would like to include 'bico/header.jinja2'. The thing is that I don't want to write the 'arby/' or 'bico/' prefix in the {% include 'arby/base.jinja2' %}. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: From what file are you running `import`?

Comment: from 'arby/base.jinja2'. I would like to use {%import 'header.jinja2'%} to include 'arby/header.jinja2'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a hint in the [jinja2.Environment.join_path()](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment.join_path) docstring about subclassing Environment and overriding the join_path() method to support `import` paths relative to the current (i.e., the *parent* argument of join_path) template.

Here is an example of such a class:

```
import posixpath
class RelEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):
    """Override join_path() to enable relative template paths."""
    def join_path(self, template, parent):
        return posixpath.join(posixpath.dirname(parent), template)
```

Comment: Careful - this doesn't work on windows because of Jinja issues 411 and 412 - os.path.dirname and os.path.join will use `'\\'`, which FilesystemLoader will reject. Make sure the result is separated with `'/'` instead of `os.path.sep`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor you are right. i have been struggle due to this for the last few hours. this must be put in some docs

Comment: You can use posixpath instead of os.path for this then

Answer (score 1):

This is answer is coming late, but for anynone having this issue, you could do it like so in base.jinja2

```
{%import 'arby/header.jinja2' as header%}
```

jinja should know the path to templates so specifying a file in a subfolder in templates should be easy as the folder/file.extension.

**Note**: coming from flask pespective

Comment: This ignores the premise of the question entirely lol

Comment: Still the same issue, what I need is to specify the template directory in such a way that it is relative the the original script location not the location the script is run from.