# Flask/Jinja2 - Include template relative to current template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there a syntax for referencing a local file? For example

Instead of having to write :

```
{% include 'user/project/task/task_detail/tab.html' %}
```

I want to write (from a template that's in the same directory as tab.html):

```
{% include './tab.html' %}
```

But the above raises `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass Jinja's Environment and override the join_path() method to support import paths relative to the current directory.

```
class RelativeEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):
    """Override join_path() to enable relative template paths."""
    def join_path(self, template, parent):
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(parent), template)
```

However please mind that Jinja's mechanism of finding templates is designed in order to disambiguate templates' paths.

You can read more at https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.join_path

This question is a possible duplicate of [How to include a template with relative path in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512677/how-to-include-a-template-with-relative-path-in-jinja2/8530761)

Comment: Having trouble finding documentation about how to use such a subclass in Jinja/Flask. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Flask/j2 needs to know the structure to find a file, and it knowns the basic structure of app subfolders (static, templates etc.).
The best way is to put it in a static subfolders and then point at it using the `url_for` function:

```
..."{{ url_for('static', filename='<subfolder>/tab.html') }}"...
`
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for